# Titlebar get into ToggleButton in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, togglebutton, titlebar

i'm tyring to create a `togglebutton` in `toolbar` with this code : 
[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#acacac">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#acacac"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#202020" />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/check"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

but when i set title the title get into or becomes merged with a togglebutton:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
settitle("stackoverflow");
```

Comment: where do you want it to appear left right or below?

Comment: @Xenolion lwhen i set  a small title i don't have a problem but when i set a big  title , title text get into togglebutton like this 
https://i.imgur.com/pTTHtu0.png

Comment: So are you okay if the word will have to be like **stack overflow bla... (the toggle button here)** see the three dots it doesnt touch

Comment: @Xenolion yeah i'm ok with that only thing i don't want it's title merged with toggle button like picture

Comment: I am giving a solution now gimme 2 minutes.

Comment: @Xenolion thanks so much take your time

Comment: Your answer is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news about `Toolbar` not like the old `ActionBar` is that Toolbars are easily customizable. This is how I have customized your layout. First I have added the horizontal linear layout `Linear Layout` as a view in your Toolbar. And I have removed the `ToggleButton` and added it inside in `LinearLayout` just after the a `TextView` which will now be your app title. And If you don't mind you can set the title directly using XML So this is your new `Toolbar` Please first delete ( or hide) your `ToogleButton` and `Toolbar` and paste the following code in place where your `Toolbar` was.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="title here or even @string/Something"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**This is how it looks in my Android Studio So far:**
When you want to set your text is longer you will see the dots (**...**) When its smaller you see it all.

[image: Showing Longer words cropped]

**From now one lets Talks about changes in your code.**
 Your `Toolbar` title will be the Value in your `TextView` you no longer need the line.

```
toolbar.setTitle("stackoverflow");
```

You can use your `TextView` directly in `xml` or in `Java` code. Remember you can also increase `TextSize` just like a normal Layout. In code you can use

```
TextView text_title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
text_title.setText("stack Overflow");
```

**Happy Coding!**